# How can I set the current page of a TPageControl?

Tags: delphi, tpagecontrol

I am using a pagecontrol component and I need to add a button and click it to go to a specified page.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a button to the form and write an OnClick event handler like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PageControl1.ActivePage := TabSheet1;
end;
```

Comment: @Satch3000, good suggestion but note that this will not trigger an OnPageChange event for the PageControl, if you want **that** to happen you'll need to call that event in your `Button1Click` explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

You can use ActivePageIndex:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := 0;
end;
```

Comment: This is equivalent to using `ActivePage`, the two properties are synonymous

Comment: I would still prefer setting ActivePage, because the index of a page is variable. Or at least: has that ability. The reference to a page on the other hand will always stay the same. And most likely will the code be more readable with a self-descriptive variable name than with a meaningless digit.

Comment: I think it depends on situation. Many times I used ActivePageIndex set to 0 on formShow to be sure that first one will be visible on start. After rearenging tabsheets code its still ok.

Comment: Well, that's hardly a _situation_, but just a knack to reset the changes you've made in the designer. ;) Good tip though! +1

Answer (score 1):

Can I just add that you cannot set the active page within the OnChange event (I tried for ages!).  Any checks that are needed must be done within the OnChanging event and then set the Allowchange var to true or false accordingly:

```
procedure Tfrm_AspireParams.PC_OptionsChanging(Sender: TObject;
  var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
 AllowChange := true;
 if fActivated then
 begin
   if BBtn_Timesheets_Save.Enabled then  // They have not saved changes on this tab.
   begin
     messagedlg('Please save the page first', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
     AllowChange := False;
   end;
 end;

end;
```